# MAAS - listed nodes not booting

Tags: maas

after having used Ubuntu for 4 years, I started playing around with Ubuntu for servers, MAAS, that kind of stuff and come to the conclusion that I totally suck at it.

I need help! I have been installing, reinstalling MAAS on an old PC of mine and I get the whole thing so far that I can login to the system on $ http://xx.xx.xx.15/MAAS. However from there it goes wrong...partly I guess because I don know what I´m doing.

- It starts with DNS & DHCP management: I have a network in my house with a Cisco router which has the option switched on for DHCP server. Does this mean, I should not interfere with the router? Or shall I switch it off and build my own thing? At the moment, I let MAAS still do the DNS&DHCP managment.
- After that: adding nodes in de UI seems easy to do. I can even find and list them in command line. However when, I want to do $ maas maas nodes accept-all, it gives me ´[]´ and for the rest the node does not perform anything.

The documentation for MAAS (http://maas.ubuntu.com/docs/index.html) was probably meant for smarter people, at least I don´t get what I´m doing wrong. I guess what I am missing is a step-by-step tutorial that explains every single box that I have to fill in. Apparently, I don fill them in correctly.

Would be very thankful for help.

Greets,
aqua

Comment: Wondering if you ever got this working? I'm doing a similar thing as you were attempting. My problem seems to be that the nodes will not commission.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have done everything right except for, most likely, the networking. The easiest way to get MAAS working right without interfering with the rest of your network is to enable MAAS control of DHCP and DNS, and to put the nodes on a separate network. So, your MAAS controller would have two NICs - one connected to the rest of your network, one connected to a switch which all the intended nodes are also connected to.

You can have them all on the same network, but it means manually configuring the DHCP and DNS (which MAAS requires to know where the nodes are on the network, and boot them) which can be a good deal trickier. see http://maas.ubuntu.com/docs/configure.html#manual-dhcp-configuration

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply, nick. I have added another (assumably virtual) network to my MAAS (10.0.0.0/16) & added another interface (eth1) to my cluster controller (10.0.0.0/16). i have commissioned a node to this new network, but still i cannot get the node to work. Btw, when building a node, it continuously asks me to specify a power type and a MAC. Can I freely appoint a power type and MAC to this node?

Comment: hmmm, i just realized my node doesnt have any ip-adresses (¨ip_addresses¨: []). That´s odd, no?!

Comment: what hardware are you using for this setup? Are you using a single box and virtual nodes? If so, how are you virtualising them?
It is certainly possible to set up MAAS in such an environment, but the networking also becomes more complex in some ways, because you have to configure the virtual network properly as well.